# How to call an element in a Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This looked like a very simple question but I couldn't find the answer.
How to call an element in an Numpy array?

```py
import numpy as np
    
arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]])
    
print arr(0,0)
```

The code above doesn't work.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Just use square brackets instead:

```
print arr[0,0]
```

Comment: +1. Extra info: numpy arrays are 0-based, that means if you want to get the 1 from the array you should use `arr[0,0]` instead of `arr[1,1]`.

Answer (score 11):

**TL;DR**:

Using [slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> arr = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]])
>>> 
>>> arr[0,0]
1
>>> arr[1,1]
7
>>> arr[1,0]
6
>>> arr[1,-1]
10
>>> arr[1,-2]
9
```

---

**In Long:**

Hopefully this helps in your understanding:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ])
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> x = np.array([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ])
>>> x[1][2] # 2nd row, 3rd column 
6
>>> x[1,2] # Similarly
6
```

But to appreciate why [slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) is useful, in more dimensions:

```
>>> np.array([ [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]] ])
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12]]])
>>> x = np.array([ [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]] ])

>>> x[1][0][2] # 2nd matrix, 1st row, 3rd column
9
>>> x[1,0,2] # Similarly
9

>>> x[1][0:2][2] # 2nd matrix, 1st row, 3rd column
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

>>> x[1, 0:2, 2] # 2nd matrix, 1st and 2nd row, 3rd column
array([ 9, 12])

>>> x[1, 0:2, 1:3] # 2nd matrix, 1st and 2nd row, 2nd and 3rd column
array([[ 8,  9],
       [11, 12]])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `numpy` and your array is an `np.array` of `np.array` elements like:

`A = np.array([np.array([10,11,12,13]), np.array([15,16,17,18]), np.array([19,110,111,112])])`

and you want to access the inner elements (like `10,11,12 13,14.......`) then use:

`A[0][0]` instead of `A[0,0]`

For example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>>A = np.array([np.array([10,11,12,13]), np.array([15,16,17,18]), np.array([19,110,111,112])])
>>> A[0][0]
>>> 10
>>> A[0,0]
>>> Throws ERROR
```

(P.S.: Might be useful when using `numpy.array_split()`)

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could try to use `ndarray.item()`, for example, `arr.item((0, 0))`(rowid+colid to index) or `arr.item(0)`(flatten index), its doc https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy. array. flatten() to convert a 2D NumPy array into a 1D array
print(array_2d)
array_1d = array_2d. flatten() flatten `array_2d`
print(array_1d)