# prefered method to get an element of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Looking at a numpy array, i find **two methods** to get an element from the answers given to this question: [How to call an element in a numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582601/how-to-call-an-element-in-a-numpy-array).

There are the two methods:
`a[i][j]` or `a[i,j]`

Here is a minimum reproducable example:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(15).reshape(3, 5)
'''
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
'''


print(a[1][1])  # returns 6
print(a[1,1])   # return 6
```

Both appear to give the same result, so is one method better than the other ?

Comment: `a[1][1]` is more work because numpy has to create an array view `a[1]` only for accessing a single element from it before the view object is thrown away (also work).

Comment: While for accessing an element at a specific position in a N-dim array, the single `getitem()` call is the preferred one, there are cases where multiple calls to `getitem()` are difficult to express otherwise (e.g. when they are both a list of indices, or slices).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a[1][1]
```

Returns the slice `a[1]` and then indexes that slice at `[1]`

```
a[1] -> array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])[1] -> 6
```

Whereas

```
a[1, 1]
```

Does the same end-result calculation but all within the numpy API in C, so is faster:

```
a[1][1]
360 ns ± 28.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

a[1, 1]
191 ns ± 2.76 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
```

Comment: okay,  so according to the above the answer is without a doubt `a[i,j]`.  Is there a case where `a[i][j]` is preferred in that respect?

Comment: @D.L. I cant think off the top of my head any time I would use `a[i][j]` over `a[i, j]`

Comment: So this answer shows a 2x gain (approximately).  question:  why did you use *1 mill loops* vs *10 mill loops* in the speed calculation ?  (logical to test on the same size).

Comment: @D.L this is what `timeit` uses by default -- tweak the number of loops to give a reasonable estimate within reasonable time.

Answer (score 4):

You have the answer in the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#basic-indexing)

> Note that if one indexes a multidimensional array with fewer indices than dimensions, one gets a subdimensional array. For example:
>
> ```
> x[0]
> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
> ```
>
> That is, each index specified selects the array corresponding to the
> rest of the dimensions selected. In the above example, choosing 0
> means that the remaining dimension of length 5 is being left
> unspecified, and that what is returned is an array of that
> dimensionality and size. It must be noted that the returned array is a
> view, i.e., it is not a copy of the original, but points to the same
> values in memory as does the original array. In this case, the 1-D
> array at the first position (0) is returned. So using a single index
> on the returned array, results in a single element being returned.
> That is:
>
> ```
> x[0][2]
> 2
> ```
>
> So note that `x[0, 2] == x[0][2]` though the second case is
> more inefficient as a new temporary array is created after the first
> index that is subsequently indexed by 2.

Answer (score 3):

### Single element indexing

Single element indexing works exactly like that for other standard Python sequences. It is 0-based, and accepts negative indices for indexing from the end of the array.

```
x = np.arange(10)
x[2]
2
x[-2]
8
```

It is not necessary to separate each dimension’s index into its own set of square brackets.

```
x.shape = (2, 5)  # now x is 2-dimensional
x[1, 3]
8
x[1, -1]
9
```

Note that if one indexes a multidimensional array with fewer indices than dimensions, one gets a subdimensional array. For example:

```
x[0]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

That is, each index specified selects the array corresponding to the rest of the dimensions selected. In the above example, choosing 0 means that the remaining dimension of length 5 is being left unspecified, and that what is returned is an array of that dimensionality and size. It must be noted that the returned array is a view, i.e., it is not a copy of the original, but points to the same values in memory as does the original array. In this case, the 1-D array at the first position (0) is returned. So using a single index on the returned array, results in a single element being returned. That is:

```
x[0][2]
2
```

**So note that x[0, 2] == x[0][2] though the second case is more inefficient as a new temporary array is created after the first index that is subsequently indexed by 2.**

> Note
>
> NumPy uses C-order indexing. That means that the last index usually
> represents the most rapidly changing memory location, unlike Fortran
> or IDL, where the first index represents the most rapidly changing
> location in memory. This difference represents a great potential for
> confusion.

[source](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html)